# Highcharts, how to convert series array to hash with extra data?

Tags: highcharts

I'm inheriting a chart that someone else has already written. I now want to add extra data to the series to be displayed in the tooltip.

The original code is setup with arrays or arrays to build the series data, like so:

```
$data['series'][$nextindex]['data'][] = array(strtotime($date) * 1000, $budgetSum);
```

When I dump the array the output is like so:

```
[
    {
        "name": "Adjusted Budget",
        "color": "#7570B3",
        "data": [
            [
                1486454400000,
                0
            ],
            [
                1493622000000,
                2200
            ],
            [
                1494226800000,
                3700
            ],
....
```

I know to add extra data it needs to be formatted as a hash/object:

```
[
  {x: 1486454400000, y: 0, myData: test1},
  {x: 1493622000000, y: 2200, myData: test2},
  {x: 1494226800000, y: 3700, myData: test3},
  .....
]
```

I'm just not sure how to do the conversion...
I tried something like this (but it didn't work):

```
$myArr = array('x' => strtotime($date) * 1000, 'y' => $budgetSum, 'myData' => 'test1');
$data['series'][$nextindex]['data'][] = json_encode($myArr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I was overthinking it.
I got it to work with:

```
$myArr = array('x' => strtotime($date) * 1000, 'y' => $budgetSum, 'myData' => 'test1');
$data['series'][$nextindex]['data'][] = $myArr;
```

No need for the **json_encode()**